# How can I use multiple scopes to construct a query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

First: suppose I have a User class and would like to create User scopes outside of the User class. For example, I have a Book class and I'd like it to return a scope for users who would like to read that book:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

  def interested_users
    Users.scoped.where(sql_for_they_would_like_to_read_this_book)
  end
end
```

Now, suppose I have an array of books, and I'd like to generate a scope for users who would like to read all books. How do I apply these several scopes together?

```
def union_scopes(scope1, scope2)
  ???
end

would_like_to_read_all_books = User.scope
books.each do |book|
  would_like_to_read_all_books = union_scopes(user_scope, book.interested_users)
end
```

I know that if the scope was defined on User I could do 
`User.interested_in_book(book1).interested_in_book(book2) ...` 
but that's not where I want it.

Comment: if you have raw sql, you wont be able to leverage scope goodness

Comment: What apneadiving said. You should use `Arel`: https://github.com/rails/arel

Comment: @FarleyKnight it's not clear to me how Arel would help (having used it before and just looked through documentation again). Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

Looks like `merge` can be used:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge